# RegEx Match Repetitive Words - same line separated by a space

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

Need a RegEx to match 2 consecutive repetitive words on either side of a space

I am doing a data cleanse, and in this case it is the First Name field.

So I want to find a Regex that will find invalid First Names.

So things like:

```
David David  

Steve Steve

Mary Mary
```

Basically I need to find entries where some sort of data entry issues have occurred and a persons' first name has been entered 2x into the First Name field.

Hopefully this clarifies ))

Please help, I'm stuck.

Tnx

Comment: Please consider bookmarking the [Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/2736496) for future reference. Welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that use backreferences:

`(\w+) \1`

### Demo

The `\number` [*backreferences*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/thwdfzxy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) are used to refer to captured groups in the expression. In this case, the first captured group was `(\w+)` and therefore, the above regex will match a string which is two same words separated by a space.

Comment: Very nice! Seems to work for what I'm looking for... I could have sworn it would have been a more complicated regex than that... I am new to it tho.. thanks a bunch mate!